# Computing the contour integral of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, evaluate $\displaystyle{\int_{|z|=1} \dfrac{e^{z}}{z^n}dz}$.

My intuition tells me that I can use the Cauchy Integral Formula since the function, $f(z)$ has $n$ singular points, being $z=0$ which lie entirely in the unit circle.

My solution is as follows:

$${\int_{|z|=1} \dfrac{e^{z}}{z^n}dz}=\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{e^{z}}{(z_{1}-0)^n}+...+\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{e^{z}}{(z_{n}-0)^n}  =n[2\pi i.f(0)]=2\pi nei,$$ where $f(0)= \dfrac{e^{0}}{(z-0)^0} = 1.$

Can someone tell me if i am on the right track and how can i correct my solution if i am wrong. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the  [Cauchy's integral formula Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) in the correct way.  Recall the [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) and use it with $a=0$ and $f(z)=e^z$: for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$,
$$\int_{|z|=1} \dfrac{f(z)}{z^n}dz=2\pi i \cdot\frac{ f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}.$$
For $n=0$ the integral is zero by [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your hint. Could you kindly guide me further with some starting starting steps as i am rather new to this module on complex analysis.

Comment: You are not using Cauchy Integral Formula correctly. Recall the statement and try again. Note that the derivative of $e^z$ is again $e^z$.

Comment: Thanks again for your guidance. I've got it.